# How to fix navigator / window / document is undefined in Nuxt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I was trying to determined UserAgent and Retina info inside Nuxt application. But the application is throwing an error and showing navigatior / window is undefined. How can i get these info inside nuxt application?

```js
const userAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()
const isAndroid = userAgent.includes('android')
```

```js
isRetina() {
  let mediaQuery
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && window !== null) {
    mediaQuery =
      '(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25), (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25), (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 5/4), (min-resolution: 1.25dppx)'
    if (window.devicePixelRatio > 1.25) {
      return true
    }
    if (window.matchMedia && window.matchMedia(mediaQuery).matches) {
      return true
    }
  }
  return false
}
```

Comment: Hi for some reason even after following the steps you have mentioned it does not seem to work and I am getting `document is not defined` error. I have posted my question here can you please help me out with this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/69814456/7584240

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is the solution to fix:

- `navigator is undefined`
- `window is undefined`
- `document is not defined`

---

Here is an example on how you should wrap your logic JS code

```html
<script>
import { jsPlumb } from 'jsplumb' // client-side library only, no SSR support

export default {
  mounted() {
    if (process.client) {
      // your JS code here like >> jsPlumb.ready(function () {})
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

As shown here: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/internals-glossary/context

PS: `mounted` + `process.client` are kinda redundant because `mounted` only runs on [the client](https://nuxtjs.org/pt/docs/concepts/nuxt-lifecycle#client).

---

Also, wrapping your component into `<client-only>` if you want it to be only client side rendered is also a good idea.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <p>this will be rendered on both: server + client</p>
    
    <client-only>
      <p>this one will only be rendered on client</p>
    </client-only>
  <div>
</template>
```

The documentation for this one is here: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/nuxt-components/#the-client-only-component

PS: beware because this `client-only` tag will only skip the rendering, not the execution, as [explained here](https://deltener.com/blog/common-problems-with-the-nuxt-client-only-component/).

---

Some packages do not support SSR when you **import** them, for that you could either:

- use a condition with a [dynamic import](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67825061/8816585) (if the library is meant to be used later on)
- directly like this (if you want to load a component like [`vue-editor`](https://github.com/davidroyer/vue2-editor))

```js
export default {
  components: {
    [process.client && 'VueEditor']: () => import('vue2-editor'),
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to assign then a name to the component with this syntax? (I'm trying to use this trick with `VueTouch`, but I have to name it `v-touch` to make it work)

Comment: @Joe82 `[process.client && 'VTouch'] ...` should do the trick yeah.

Comment: With `[process.client && 'VTouch']` I get `Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.`, and with `[process.client && 'VueTouch']`  I get `Unknown custom element: <v-touch> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.`

Comment: @Joe82 it looks like vue-touch is not compatible/maintained anymore: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-touch Are you talking about another package? Feel free to open a new question and mention this answer. I'll help you more in-depth. :)