# jsPlumb integration with Nuxtjs throwing the error document is not defined

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, nuxt.js, jsplumb

I know there are a few questions similar to this but they did not work for me so I am posting this.

I am trying to add `jsPlumb` into my `Nuxtjs/Vuejs` application. I did the following steps:

1. `npm i jsplumb --save`
2. Create a `Vuejs` page and add the simple code:

```html
<template>
  <client-only>
    <div id="canvas" />
  </client-only>
</template>

<script>
import { jsPlumb } from 'jsplumb'

export default {
  mounted () {
    if (process.client) {
      console.log('MOUNTED - 2')
      jsPlumb.ready(function () {
        console.log('MOUNTED - 3')
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I get the error:

```
ReferenceError
document is not defined
```

I tried many things which were mentioned but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix navigator / window / document is undefined in Nuxt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67751476/how-to-fix-navigator-window-document-is-undefined-in-nuxt)

Comment: @kissu Thanks for your response. But I have tried that answer but it did not work for me. If you check my code its the same.

Comment: Some solutions here could also be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69572014/8816585 I guess I tried it last time and it worked.

Comment: @kissu I tried everything but nothing seem to work for me. I have modified the code can you please check and let me know what am I doing wrong? I checked many answers and all seem to address the same but for some reason it does not work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `process.client` I used the `process.browser` and it worked fine for me. Please refer the link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69822954/7584240