# WebSocket is not defined with NuxtJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, websocket, nuxt.js

So I want to make a web socket client using a VueJs using NuxtJs framework, this is My component

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      connection: null,
    }
  },
  created() {
    console.log("Starting connection to WebSocket Server")
    this.connection = new WebSocket("wss://echo.websocket.org")

    this.connection.onmessage = function(event) {
      console.log(event);
    }

    this.connection.onopen = function(event) {
      console.log(event)
      console.log("Successfully connected to the echo websocket server...")
    }
  },
  head() {
    return {
      title: 'Web Socket',
      meta: [
        {
          hid: 'description',
          name: 'description',
          content: 'Web socket'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

And I got this message
[image: Error message]

I'm using Ms Edge for the browser, I tried using a vue-native-socket, and other socket package, but still get the same error 'Websocket not defined'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm no Websocket expert, but to my knowledge, this is something available only on client side.
You may try to follow up this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67751550/8816585

```js
created() {
  if (process.client) {
    // the code in this block will only run on client side
    console.log("Starting connection to WebSocket Server")
    this.connection = new WebSocket("wss://echo.websocket.org")

    this.connection.onmessage = function(event) {
      console.log(event);
    }

    this.connection.onopen = function(event) {
      console.log(event)
      console.log("Successfully connected to the echo websocket server...")
    }
  }
}
```

This will prevent the code written inside of the `created()` hook to be triggered on both server and client side (hence the error on the server). Because `created()` is available on both server and client side, as explained here: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/concepts/nuxt-lifecycle/