# Shaka player - HTMLMediaElement is not defined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, video-player, shaka

When I installed [shaka player](https://github.com/google/shaka-player) in Nuxt and `mode: universal`, I received this error:

[image]

In `spa` mode shaka is working but in `universal` it doesn't work.

---

Thanks to the answer, the issue was solved with the following:

```js
if (process.client) {
  window.shaka = require('shaka-player/dist/shaka-player.compiled.js')
  require('shaka-player/dist/shaka-player.ui')
}
```

Comment: Please check this on for `mode` tho: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68272663/8816585 As this is currently deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not provided any code, but I'm 90% sure that this is coming from the fact that `window` is not present when run on the server.

My answer can be found here: [How to fix navigator / window / document is undefined in Nuxt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67751550/8816585)