# Why does vue-plyr plugin keep loading on server side

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a nuxt app which uses the [vue-plyr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@skjnldsv/vue-plyr) plugin to play videos. I've registered the plugin like this

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VuePlyr from 'vue-plyr/dist/vue-plyr.ssr.js'
import 'vue-plyr/dist/vue-plyr.css'

Vue.use(VuePlyr, {
  plyr: {}
})
```

and added it to `nuxt.config.js`

```js
plugins: [
  {
    src: '~/plugins/plyr.client.js',
    mode: 'client'
  }
],
```

but when I import it inside a component

```js
import VuePlyr from 'vue-plyr'
```

I always get an error saying

> document is not defined

The component itself is also wrapped in a `<client-only></client-only>` tag.

Am i missing something with my implementation?
Is there any other way to import the plugin

I'm using `node-14.17.6` and `nuxt-2.15.6`

Comment: On top of what I've wrote, I tried it on my machine with the following template and it works flawlessly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `plyr.client.js` but `plyr.js` if you already have `mode: 'client'`.
Also, why do you import it again if you have it as a plugin? It is globally available so you could start using it directly.

```html
<template>
  <client-only>
    <vue-plyr>
      <div class="plyr__video-embed">
        <iframe
          src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/bTqVqk7FSmY?amp;iv_load_policy=3&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;playsinline=1&amp;showinfo=0&amp;rel=0&amp;enablejsapi=1"
          allowfullscreen
          allowtransparency
          allow="autoplay"
        ></iframe>
      </div>
    </vue-plyr>
  </client-only>
</template>
```

Depending on the code you're using below, you may also check that this is not being called server side as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67751550/8816585

---

Updated with a more explicit example.

Comment: thank you for opening my eyes. the import was the problem the whole time.