# VueEditor document is not defined Nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, nuxt.js

In my Nuxt.js project I installed `vue2-editor` package to be able to write articles with HTML. When I come to page, write something and press the button everything works correctly, but when I reload page, I get `document is not defined` error.

Here is the code:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <SideBar />
    <div class='content'>
      <h1>Write article</h1>
      <client-only>
        <VueEditor
          v-model='articleContent'
        />
      </client-only>
      <div style='margin-top: 15px'><button @click='postArticle'>Post article</button></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { VueEditor } from 'vue2-editor';
import SideBar from '../components/SideBar';
export default {
  name: 'Articles',
  components: {
    SideBar,
    VueEditor
  },
  data() {
    return {
      articleContent: null,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    postArticle() {
      console.log(this.articleContent)
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

And the error looks like that:

[image]

Also in documentation I've found that for Nuxt.js projects `vue2-editor` should be added to `modules`, and I did it, but it still doesn't work:

```
  modules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/axios
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    'vue2-editor/nuxt'
  ],
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix navigator / window / document is undefined in Nuxt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67751476/how-to-fix-navigator-window-document-is-undefined-in-nuxt)

Comment: Hi, please make a quick search before posting a question next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to load it dynamically:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <SideBar />
    <div class='content'>
      <h1>Write article</h1>
      <client-only>
        <VueEditor
          v-model='articleContent'
        />
      </client-only>
      <div style='margin-top: 15px'><button @click='postArticle'>Post article</button></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import SideBar from '../components/SideBar';
export default {
  name: 'Articles',
  components: {
    SideBar,
    VueEditor: () => process.client ? (await import("vue2-editor")).VueEditor : ""
  },
  data() {
    return {
      articleContent: null,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    postArticle() {
      console.log(this.articleContent)
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do follow the below steps the add that plugin into your Nuxt

- There will be `plugins` folder just like `pages` and `components`, if not create one and add a `js` file into it `vue2-editor.js`.
- Copy the below content inside `vue2-editor.js`

  ```
    import Vue from "vue";
    import Vue2Editor from "vue2-editor";

    Vue.use(Vue2Editor);
  ```
- Inside `nuxt.config.js` remove the `'vue2-editor/nuxt'` from the modules and create a separate array called plugins as below

```js
  /*
  ** Plugins to load before mounting the App
  */
 plugins: [{ src: "~/plugins/vue2-editor", mode: 'client' }],
```

- Thats it you are done. Now you can start using it in any of the vue files like

```
  <vue-editor placeholder="Write Something..." v-model="content"></vue-editor>
```