# google/model-viewer with nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, model-viewer

I'm a bit clueless with integrating the *[@google/model-viewer](https://github.com/google/model-viewer)* into a nuxtjs project:

This is my *model-viewer.js* in the *plugins* folder

```
import Vue from "vue";
import modelViewer from "@google/model-viewer";

Vue.use(modelViewer);
```

The part in my *nuxt.config.js*

```
  plugins: [
    "@/plugins/hooks",
    { src: "@/plugins/gsap", mode: "client" },
    { src: "@/plugins/model-viewer", mode: "client" },
  ],
```

... and the component so far

```
<template>
    <model-viewer
      :src="src"
      bounds="tight"
      enable-pan
      camera-controls
      environment-image="neutral"
      poster="poster.webp"
      shadow-intensity="1"
      autoplay
    ></model-viewer>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
export default {
  ssr: false,
  name: "Viewer3d",
  props: {
    src: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  setup() {
    return {};
  },
};
</script>
```

When called I get the Error

> Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                                                                            friendly-errors 13:36:36
>
> ERROR  in
> ./node_modules/@google/model-viewer/dist/model-viewer.min.js
> friendly-errors 13:36:36
>
> Module parse failed: Unexpected token (999:5963)
> friendly-errors 13:36:36 You may need an appropriate loader to handle
> this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this
> file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders |  * limitations
> under the License. |  */

and a

> window is not defined

from my browser.

What am I missing? I am not familiar with loaders in nuxt and wasn't able to find something helping me with my problem.

Comment: Hi, can you please try this one? https://stackoverflow.com/a/67751550/8816585

Comment: What exactly? My import is from a file in the nuxt plugins folder and is set to only on client side. The "client-only" wrapper doesn't do anything here, unfortunately. :/

Answer (score 1):

Currently with NuxtJS updating the model viewer library to version 3, I have been able to make it work, until now I had to keep it on v1.12 which was the latest that worked for me.

The model-viewer.js in the plugins folder

```
import '@google/model-viewer';
```

And you need to wrap the model-viewer tag with the client-only

```js
    <template>
      <client-only>
        <model-viewer
          :src="src"
          bounds="tight"
          enable-pan
          camera-controls
          environment-image="neutral"
          poster="poster.webp"
          shadow-intensity="1"
          autoplay
        ></model-viewer>
      </client-only>
    </template>
    <script lang="ts">
    export default {
      ssr: false,
      name: "Viewer3d",
      props: {
        src: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
      },
      setup() {
        return {};
      },
    };
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but with NuxtJS. Try to use an older version of the model-viewer, everything until version 1.10.1 is working for me.