# Not able to preview NuxtJs3 build

Tags: nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

My Nuxt 3 Project is suddenly giving me some error after release of 3.0.0-rc.5, it used to work well and now i am not able to find, what is actually causing this error.

in dev mode, everything works fine. application runs properly.
even when i run build command, it doesn't throw any error, build is getting done succesfully, but

> when i do yarn run preview then it gives me following error.

```
  [nuxt] [request error] Invalid value used as weak map key
  at WeakMap.set (<anonymous>)  
  at normalizePropsOptions (./server/chunks/handlers/renderer.mjs:5605:12)  
  at createComponentInstance (./server/chunks/handlers/renderer.mjs:8088:24)  
  at renderComponentVNode (./server/chunks/handlers/renderer.mjs:10509:22)  
  at Object.ssrRenderComponent (./server/chunks/handlers/renderer.mjs:10946:12)  
  at ./server/chunks/app/index.6084a03b.mjs:137:36  
  at renderComponentSubTree (./server/chunks/handlers/renderer.mjs:10591:13)  
  at ./server/chunks/handlers/renderer.mjs:10523:29  
  at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)  
  at async unrollBuffer (./server/chunks/handlers/renderer.mjs:10743:24)
```

> this is after yarn build command

```
rishavkumar@Rishavs-MacBook-Pro TripClubNuxt3 % yarn build
yarn run v1.22.5
$ nuxt build
Nuxt CLI v3.0.0-rc.5                                                                                                       03:58:09
ℹ Vite client warmed up in 12607ms                                                                                         03:58:25
ℹ Client built in 23855ms                                                                                                  03:58:36
ℹ Building server...                                                                                                       03:58:36

 WARN  mdi-vue doesn't appear to be written in CJS, but also doesn't appear to be a valid ES module (i.e. it doesn't have "type": "module" or an .mjs extension for the entry point). Please contact the package author to fix.

✔ Server built in 94ms                                                                                                     03:58:37
✔ Generated public .output/public                                                                                    nitro 03:58:48
start Building server...                                                                                             nitro 03:58:48
start Writing server bundle...                                                                                       nitro 03:59:34
✔ Server built                                                                                                       nitro 03:59:37
  ├─ .output/server/package.json (587 B) (277 B gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/index.mjs (458 B) (257 B gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/rollup/carousel.mjs.map (99 B) (101 B gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/rollup/carousel.mjs (95 B) (95 B gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/nitro/node-server.mjs.map (63 kB) (4.45 kB gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/nitro/node-server.mjs (183 kB) (37.7 kB gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/handlers/renderer.mjs.map (1.92 MB) (91.3 kB gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/handlers/renderer.mjs (431 kB) (98.7 kB gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/things-to-do-in-_country_.a91ec7ee.mjs.map (9.05 kB) (2.29 kB gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/things-to-do-in-_country_.a91ec7ee.mjs (12.6 kB) (3.28 kB gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/things-to-do-in-_city_.71258e9e.mjs.map (6.54 kB) (1.66 kB gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/things-to-do-in-_city_.71258e9e.mjs (9.39 kB) (2.68 kB gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/terms-of-use.28c2745f.mjs.map (884 B) (442 B gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/terms-of-use.28c2745f.mjs (50.5 kB) (14.5 kB gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/server.mjs.map (2.01 MB) (253 kB gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/server.mjs (1.78 MB) (358 kB gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/search.d38c3de5.mjs.map (557 B) (318 B gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/search.d38c3de5.mjs (837 B) (423 B gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/reviews.67b52bad.mjs.map (866 B) (430 B gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/reviews.67b52bad.mjs (1.22 kB) (585 B gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/review.4b6a37fd.mjs.map (557 B) (318 B gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/review.4b6a37fd.mjs (838 B) (426 B gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/results.bee98cf9.mjs.map (11.9 kB) (3.16 kB gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/results.bee98cf9.mjs (12.4 kB) (3.71 kB gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/results.29a91765.mjs.map (559 B) (319 B gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/results.29a91765.mjs (845 B) (430 B gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/refunds-policy.61e6e40e.mjs.map (886 B) (441 B gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/refunds-policy.61e6e40e.mjs (7.18 kB) (2.97 kB gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/privacy-policy.c8dddcfb.mjs.map (889 B) (441 B gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/privacy-policy.c8dddcfb.mjs (17.8 kB) (5.92 kB gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/listing.9a8ebae0.mjs.map (559 B) (318 B gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/listing.9a8ebae0.mjs (841 B) (424 B gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/listing.0ee5c4d5.mjs.map (559 B) (319 B gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/listing.0ee5c4d5.mjs (840 B) (425 B gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/LeftOutlined.69f96e25.mjs.map (1.9 kB) (708 B gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/LeftOutlined.69f96e25.mjs (1.72 kB) (836 B gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/index.f603f53f.mjs.map (862 B) (423 B gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/index.f603f53f.mjs (1.22 kB) (586 B gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/index.ed41ba5d.mjs.map (6.58 kB) (1.73 kB gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/index.ed41ba5d.mjs (9.44 kB) (2.59 kB gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/index.dcea4be4.mjs.map (6.54 kB) (1.69 kB gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/index.dcea4be4.mjs (8.78 kB) (2.48 kB gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/index.cbe4e5a3.mjs.map (45.1 kB) (8.26 kB gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/index.cbe4e5a3.mjs (42.8 kB) (9.03 kB gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/index.c803c513.mjs.map (862 B) (424 B gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/index.c803c513.mjs (1.22 kB) (583 B gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/index.bdf5eb04.mjs.map (6.85 kB) (1.73 kB gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/index.bdf5eb04.mjs (9.73 kB) (2.92 kB gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/index.b8ddb9c1.mjs.map (7.5 kB) (2.01 kB gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/index.b8ddb9c1.mjs (6.75 kB) (2 kB gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/index.b78c01cc.mjs.map (6.85 kB) (1.73 kB gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/index.b78c01cc.mjs (9.7 kB) (2.9 kB gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/index.aea74894.mjs.map (6.85 kB) (1.72 kB gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/index.aea74894.mjs (9.72 kB) (2.91 kB gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/index.9f8c6ee3.mjs.map (7.37 kB) (1.9 kB gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/index.9f8c6ee3.mjs (11.5 kB) (3.3 kB gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/index.9062b2b1.mjs.map (1.42 kB) (612 B gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/index.9062b2b1.mjs (2.32 kB) (1 kB gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/index.8b09b807.mjs.map (3.27 kB) (950 B gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/index.8b09b807.mjs (5.34 kB) (2.06 kB gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/index.8ad962be.mjs.map (2.17 kB) (780 B gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/index.8ad962be.mjs (4.78 kB) (1.99 kB gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/index.8a6ea094.mjs.map (6.85 kB) (1.73 kB gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/index.8a6ea094.mjs (9.73 kB) (2.9 kB gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/index.7f8bc7f8.mjs.map (836 B) (419 B gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/index.7f8bc7f8.mjs (1.27 kB) (610 B gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/index.65ab0620.mjs.map (6.85 kB) (1.72 kB gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/index.65ab0620.mjs (9.71 kB) (2.91 kB gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/index.6084a03b.mjs.map (10.8 kB) (2.16 kB gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/index.6084a03b.mjs (14.6 kB) (3.26 kB gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/index.55f27981.mjs.map (1.93 kB) (763 B gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/index.55f27981.mjs (2.95 kB) (1.25 kB gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/index.52424d17.mjs.map (32.3 kB) (6.19 kB gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/index.52424d17.mjs (38.9 kB) (8.79 kB gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/index.39f15d06.mjs.map (3 kB) (867 B gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/index.39f15d06.mjs (6.75 kB) (2.49 kB gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/index.1e6785a3.mjs.map (555 B) (318 B gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/index.1e6785a3.mjs (836 B) (423 B gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/index.178400c5.mjs.map (9.7 kB) (1.96 kB gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/index.178400c5.mjs (13.1 kB) (3.09 kB gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/index.15285a80.mjs.map (6.85 kB) (1.73 kB gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/index.15285a80.mjs (9.7 kB) (2.9 kB gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/index.04a83794.mjs.map (6.32 kB) (1.65 kB gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/index.04a83794.mjs (8.67 kB) (2.32 kB gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/index.024d2273.mjs.map (829 B) (414 B gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/index.024d2273.mjs (1.07 kB) (541 B gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/hotels-in-_city_.b495498c.mjs.map (831 B) (413 B gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/hotels-in-_city_.b495498c.mjs (1.25 kB) (588 B gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/holidays-in-_island_.2fa9153e.mjs.map (860 B) (435 B gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/holidays-in-_island_.2fa9153e.mjs (1.11 kB) (554 B gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/empty.6085f7ed.mjs.map (1.03 kB) (483 B gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/empty.6085f7ed.mjs (1.38 kB) (619 B gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/details.badba208.mjs.map (559 B) (318 B gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/details.badba208.mjs (839 B) (423 B gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/default.d1bb0352.mjs.map (70.7 kB) (11.6 kB gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/default.d1bb0352.mjs (78.5 kB) (13.4 kB gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/customer-support.acd44029.mjs.map (1.17 kB) (550 B gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/customer-support.acd44029.mjs (2.3 kB) (1.06 kB gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/credits.7fe98d4d.mjs.map (866 B) (430 B gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/credits.7fe98d4d.mjs (1.22 kB) (583 B gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/copyright-policies.0547b676.mjs.map (889 B) (441 B gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/copyright-policies.0547b676.mjs (1.25 kB) (594 B gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/contact.67ca1e5f.mjs.map (871 B) (433 B gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/contact.67ca1e5f.mjs (2.05 kB) (954 B gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/client.manifest.mjs.map (19.3 kB) (1.58 kB gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/client.manifest.mjs (29.3 kB) (2.95 kB gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/careers.4891c39e.mjs.map (866 B) (429 B gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/careers.4891c39e.mjs (1.22 kB) (583 B gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/booking.76c19b69.mjs.map (559 B) (320 B gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/booking.76c19b69.mjs (850 B) (433 B gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/book.236b0b01.mjs.map (553 B) (316 B gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/book.236b0b01.mjs (833 B) (423 B gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/become-a-supplier.dcc16151.mjs.map (3.05 kB) (900 B gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/become-a-supplier.dcc16151.mjs (6.82 kB) (2.5 kB gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/_id.5c4de6b3.mjs.map (551 B) (315 B gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/_id.5c4de6b3.mjs (829 B) (420 B gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/_id.34d3f227.mjs.map (551 B) (317 B gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/_id.34d3f227.mjs (833 B) (424 B gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/_activityid_.d622e7af.mjs.map (36 kB) (6.21 kB gzip)
  └─ .output/server/chunks/app/_activityid_.d622e7af.mjs (42.2 kB) (8.17 kB gzip)
Σ Total size: 13.3 MB (2.7 MB gzip)
✔ You can preview this build using node .output/server/index.mjs                                                     nitro 03:59:38
✨  Done in 89.81s.
```

> this is my package.json

```
  {
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview",
    "start": "node .output/server/index.mjs"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss": "^5.3.0",
    "nuxt": "3.0.0-rc.3",
    "nuxt-lodash": "^2.2.0",
    "nuxt-schema-org": "^0.6.2",
    "unplugin-vue-components": "^0.21.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@ant-design/icons-vue": "^6.1.0",
    "@mdi/js": "^6.7.96",
    "@pinia/nuxt": "^0.3.0",
    "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.5.2",
    "ant-design-vue": "^3.2.10",
    "date-fns": "^2.28.0",
    "mdi-vue": "^3.0.13",
    "pinia": "^2.0.16",
    "primeicons": "^5.0.0",
    "primevue": "^3.15.0",
    "vant": "^3.5.2",
    "vue-uuid": "^3.0.0",
    "vue3-carousel": "^0.1.40",
    "vue3-google-login": "^2.0.11"
  }
}
```

this is nuxt.config

```
import { defineNuxtConfig } from 'nuxt'
import Components from 'unplugin-vue-components/vite';
import { AntDesignVueResolver } from 'unplugin-vue-components/resolvers';

// https://v3.nuxtjs.org/api/configuration/nuxt.config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    runtimeConfig: {
        public: {
            apiUrl: '', // fallback empty string, must be present tho
        },
    },

    buildModules: ['@pinia/nuxt'],

    modules: ['~/modules/device', 'nuxt-lodash', 'nuxt-schema-org'],

    css: ['~/assets/css/tailwind.css',
        'primevue/resources/themes/saga-blue/theme.css',
        'primevue/resources/primevue.css',
        'primeicons/primeicons.css'],

    build: {
        postcss: {
            postcssOptions: {
                plugins: {
                    tailwindcss: {},
                    autoprefixer: {},
                },
            },
        },
        transpile: ['primevue','vant']
    },

    lodash: {
        prefix: 'use',
        prefixSkip: ['is'],
        exclude: ['map'],
        alias: [
            ['camelCase', 'stringToCamelCase'], // => useStringToCamelCase
            ['kebabCase', 'stringToKebabCase'], // => useStringToKebabCase
        ]
    },

    vite: {
        plugins: [
            Components({
                resolvers: [AntDesignVueResolver({ resolveIcons: true })],
            }),
        ],
        // @ts-expect-error: Missing ssr key
        ssr: {
            noExternal: ['moment', 'compute-scroll-into-view', 'ant-design-vue', '@ant-design/icons-vue'],
        },
        build: {
            chunkSizeWarningLimit: 4096
        }
    },

    schemaOrg: {
        // set to your production domain  
        canonicalHost: 'https://myurl.com',
    }

})
```

> if i run yarn generate, then i get following error.

```
rishavkumar@Rishavs-MacBook-Pro TripClubNuxt3 % yarn generate
yarn run v1.22.5
$ nuxt generate
Nuxt CLI v3.0.0-rc.5                                                                                                       04:05:16
ℹ Vite client warmed up in 6232ms                                                                                          04:05:26
ℹ Client built in 21911ms                                                                                                  04:05:42
ℹ Building server...                                                                                                       04:05:42

 WARN  mdi-vue doesn't appear to be written in CJS, but also doesn't appear to be a valid ES module (i.e. it doesn't have "type": "module" or an .mjs extension for the entry point). Please contact the package author to fix.

✔ Server built in 97ms                                                                                                     04:05:42
✔ Generated public .output/public                                                                                    nitro 04:05:54
ℹ Initializing prerenderer                                                                                           nitro 04:05:54
ℹ Prerendering 1 initial routes with crawler                                                                         nitro 04:06:44

 ERROR  [unhandledRejection] document is not defined                                                                       04:06:44

  at .nuxt/prerender/chunks/app/server.mjs:395:600
  at new Promise (<anonymous>)
  at .nuxt/prerender/chunks/app/server.mjs:395:472
  at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:170:25)
  at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:178:24)
  at async .nuxt/prerender/chunks/renderer.mjs:12961:24
  at async .nuxt/prerender/chunks/renderer.mjs:13017:64
  at async node_modules/h3/dist/index.mjs:420:19
  at async nodeHandler (node_modules/h3/dist/index.mjs:370:7)
  at async ufetch (node_modules/unenv/runtime/fetch/index.mjs:9:17)


 ERROR  [nitro] [dev] [unhandledRejection] ReferenceError: document is not defined                                         04:06:44


 ERROR  [unhandledRejection] document is not defined                                                                       04:06:44

  at .nuxt/prerender/chunks/app/server.mjs:395:600
  at new Promise (<anonymous>)
  at .nuxt/prerender/chunks/app/server.mjs:395:472
  at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:170:25)
  at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:178:24)
  at async .nuxt/prerender/chunks/renderer.mjs:12961:24
  at async .nuxt/prerender/chunks/renderer.mjs:13017:64
  at async node_modules/h3/dist/index.mjs:420:19
  at async nodeHandler (node_modules/h3/dist/index.mjs:370:7)
  at async ufetch (node_modules/unenv/runtime/fetch/index.mjs:9:17)


 ERROR  [nitro] [dev] [unhandledRejection] ReferenceError: document is not defined                                         04:06:44


 ERROR  (node:27410) PromiseRejectionHandledWarning: Promise rejection was handled asynchronously (rejection id: 3)        04:06:44
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)


 WARN  [Vue warn]: Invalid vnode type when creating vnode: undefined.                                                      04:06:45


 ERROR  [nuxt] [request error] Invalid value used as weak map key                                                          04:06:45
  at WeakMap.set (<anonymous>)  
  at normalizePropsOptions (./.nuxt/prerender/chunks/renderer.mjs:6434:12)  
  at createComponentInstance (./.nuxt/prerender/chunks/renderer.mjs:9421:24)  
  at renderComponentVNode (./.nuxt/prerender/chunks/renderer.mjs:12067:22)  
  at Object.ssrRenderComponent (./.nuxt/prerender/chunks/renderer.mjs:12504:12)  
  at ./.nuxt/prerender/chunks/app/index.6084a03b.mjs:133:36  
  at renderComponentSubTree (./.nuxt/prerender/chunks/renderer.mjs:12149:13)  
  at ./.nuxt/prerender/chunks/renderer.mjs:12081:29  
  at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)  
  at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)


 ERROR  [unhandledRejection] document is not defined                                                                       04:06:45

  at .nuxt/prerender/chunks/app/server.mjs:395:600
  at new Promise (<anonymous>)
  at .nuxt/prerender/chunks/app/server.mjs:395:472
  at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:170:25)
  at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:178:24)
  at async .nuxt/prerender/chunks/renderer.mjs:12961:24
  at async .nuxt/prerender/chunks/renderer.mjs:13017:64
  at async node_modules/h3/dist/index.mjs:420:19
  at async nodeHandler (node_modules/h3/dist/index.mjs:370:7)
  at async ufetch (node_modules/unenv/runtime/fetch/index.mjs:9:17)


 ERROR  [nitro] [dev] [unhandledRejection] ReferenceError: document is not defined                                         04:06:45

  ├─ / (1576ms) (Error: [500] Internal Server Error)                                                                 nitro 04:06:45
✔ You can now deploy .output/public to any static hosting!                                                                 04:06:45
✨  Done in 89.70s.
```

> if i do node --trace-warnings ...

then i get this.

```
rishavkumar@Rishavs-MacBook-Pro TripClubNuxt3 % node --trace-warnings ...
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/rishavkumar/Documents/GitHub/TripClubNuxt3/...'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:889:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

package that is causing this error.

```
"vue3-carousel": "^0.1.40"
```

On My Page, I am using this like this.

```
<template>
<Carousel
          :items-to-show="3.5"
          :wrap-around="true"
          :breakpoints="breakpoints"
        >
          <Slide
            v-for="(item, index) in preferredTours.combinedPreferred"
            :key="index"
          >
            <ActivityCards
              :city="item.city"
              :country="item.country"
              :image="`myurl.com/activities/600p/${item.image[0].imgurl}`"
              :packagename="item.package_name"
              :price="item.price"
              :uniqueid="item.uniqueId"
              :extraclass="`ttc-w-full`"
              :slug="item.slug"
            />
          </Slide>
          <template #addons>
            <Navigation />
          </template>
        </Carousel>
</template>

<script setup>

import { ref } from "vue";
import { Carousel, Slide, Pagination, Navigation } from "vue3-carousel";
import "vue3-carousel/dist/carousel.css";

const breakpoints = {
  // 700px and up
  300: {
    itemsToShow: 2,
    snapAlign: "center",
  },
  // 700px and up
  700: {
    itemsToShow: 4,
    snapAlign: "center",
  },
  // 1024 and up
  1024: {
    itemsToShow: 4,
    snapAlign: "start",
  },
};

</script>
```

if I remove this carousel from my page, then it works fine. but earlier, it used to work well RC3 or RC4.

Comment: You have 2 issues regarding the stacktrace: the `CJS` one + the document one. Start here maybe.

Comment: Btw, do you have the issue with RC4?

Comment: @kissu - yes It used to work well in RC3/RC4. I have updated my question with the module that causing error. . in dev mode everything works well, but in build this cause error. if i remove carousel from the page, then it works well. I was using same Carousel in RC3, RC4.

Comment: Did you tried this one? https://stackoverflow.com/a/67751550/8816585

Comment: Yes, when i wrap carousel component with <client-only> then it works fine. but what caused this error. as this carousel supports SSR and it was working well in RC3, RC4. then what changed in RC5.

Comment: So, it doesn't work since the RC5? I guess this is a regression. There are some issues on the Github regarding RC4 -> RC5 indeed. Not sure if your issues fits on of those cases but you could make a [repro] and share it there: https://github.com/nuxt/framework/issues?q=is%3Aissue

Comment: Maybe try RC6, it was just released.

Comment: @kissu I tried RC6 now, it doesn't seem to help.. I will put this issue on https://github.com/nuxt/framework/issues?q=is%3Aissue