# Nuxt import highcharts for client side only

Tags: vue.js, highcharts, nuxt.js, client-side, dynamic-import

In my vue app I had following import in my component

```
import Highcharts from "highcharts";
import treemapInit from "highcharts/modules/treemap";
treemapInit(Highcharts);
```

Now I have nuxt and I need to import this part only for client side, because it fails with an error on server-side.

How to do this? Please don't suggest me Nuxt plugins, since I want to use it local due to performance.

Thanks!

Comment: Give a try to that one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67751550/8816585

Answer (score 0):

The code executes twice - on server-side and then on client-side. The first run is done in an environment that lacks `window` and causes Highcharts to be loaded, but not initialized. The fix is to place all modules inits in `if` checking if Highcharts is an object or a function. It should be an object for module initialization:

```
import Highcharts from "highcharts";
import treemapInit from "highcharts/modules/treemap";


if (typeof Highcharts === "object") {
  treemapInit(Highcharts);
}
```

---

**Docs:** https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-vue#readme

**Similar thread:** https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-vue/issues/73

Comment: I asume this will not help, as you will get an error on import statement from server side

Comment: Hi @Roman Koblents, Please check the proposed solution instead of assuming. It's the officially recommended way of using Highcharts with SSR.