# Nuxt | A mystery in addEventListener: "referenceError: window is not defined"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, navigation, nuxt.js

I am working on a hamburger menu. But i've got an error. It gives the next

[image: error (image)]

> ReferenceError: window is not defined. The fault is in the created section.

```html
<script>
export default {
    name: "navigation",
    data() {
        return {
            scrollPosition: null,
            mobile: null,
            mobileNav: null,
            windowWidth: null,
        };
    },
    created() {
        window.addEventListener("resize", this.checkScreen);
        this.checkScreen();
    },
    methods: {
        toggleMobileNav() {
            this.mobileNav = !this.mobileNav;
        },

        checkScreen() {
            this.windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
            if (this.windowWidth <= 750) {
                this.mobile = true;
                return;
            }
            this.mobile = false;
            this.mobileNav = false;
            return;
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67751550/8816585

`window` is undefined here because your code runs on both client and server side. But `window` is not available on the server side.

Check the solution for further details or use `mounted` if you're in a hurry.