# Functions in nuxt.js breaks after pushing

Tags: javascript, vue.js, deployment, axios, nuxt.js

Please, I need help.

So I write a word count function for my textarea input field. It works perfectly, then I decide to push
I delete the dist folder, do yarn generate then I push.
On pushing live, it doesn't work. It breaks the page and gives an error of my split and toString as having null values.

I return to my code locally to confirm and find out it breaks as well

It wasn't breaking before. i am surprised why this behaviour

I have tried yo rewrite the function differently to no avail

I experience this often and I always find a way to change the code. But this one is different because I have rewritten the fucntion and also taken it out of my computed to my method

PS: I am using axios to consume my APIs

Comment: Your code is probably not isomorphic (compatible on both server and client-side). Either make [a conditional](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67751550/8816585) or adapt it accordingly. Focus on debugging it locally (and think about pushing early next time, for a more efficient debugging). Please also provide more context, with a whole [repro] matching your exact errors. As of right now, the question is not answerable.

Comment: okay. Let me try further based on your suggestions.