# Nuxt 3 + TipTap 2.0.0-beta.209 | SSG | Nuxt generate creates: ERROR StarterKit.configure is not a function

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, tiptap, static-site-generation

When creating a new project using `Nuxt 3.0.0` + `TipTap 2.0.0-beta.209`, running `nuxt generate` creates the following error:

> ERROR  StarterKit.configure is not a function

> at setup (/D:/dev/nuxt-tiptap-issue/.nuxt/prerender/chunks/index.ac796611.mjs:56:20)
> at _sfc_main.setup (/D:/dev/nuxt-tiptap-issue/.nuxt/prerender/chunks/index.ac796611.mjs:321:23)
> at callWithErrorHandling (node_modules@vue\runtime-core\dist\runtime-core.cjs.prod.js:15:22)
> at setupStatefulComponent (node_modules@vue\runtime-core\dist\runtime-core.cjs.prod.js:5762:29)
> at setupComponent (node_modules@vue\runtime-core\dist\runtime-core.cjs.prod.js:5743:11)
> at renderComponentVNode (node_modules@vue\server-renderer\dist\server-renderer.cjs.prod.js:169:17)
> at renderVNode (node_modules@vue\server-renderer\dist\server-renderer.cjs.prod.js:296:22)
> at renderComponentSubTree (node_modules@vue\server-renderer\dist\server-renderer.cjs.prod.js:260:13)
> at renderComponentVNode (node_modules@vue\server-renderer\dist\server-renderer.cjs.prod.js:185:16)
> at renderVNode (node_modules@vue\server-renderer\dist\server-renderer.cjs.prod.js:296:22)

The error references to this piece of code I wrote for the WYSIWYG editor (in `pages/index.vue`)

```js
....
const editor = useEditor({
  extensions: [
    CustomDocument,
    StarterKit.configure({
      document: false,
      heading: {
        levels: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
      }
    }),
....
```

It works fine in SPA mode and `nuxt dev` also works fine.

I have created a reproduction repository here: https://github.com/CLFPosthumus/nuxt-tiptap-issue

Running `nuxt generate` also yields below warning:

```
WARN Using experimental payload extraction for full-static output. You can opt-out by setting experimental.payloadExtraction to false.
```

I tried toggling this setting, but it seems this warning is unrelated as it does not resolve the issue.

I think somehow Starterkit does not get imported correctly. But I struggle to debug/ fix this issue.

Comment: Tiptap is maybe not able to run on the server? Try to [make a conditional](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67751550/8816585) when importing it.