# I can't disable SSR of vuex-persistedstate plguin in Nuxt.js project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex

I need use vuex-persistedstate to my project, but first of all I need to set SSR equals false so I can running the project, but this error occurs: `window is not defined`. Probably because it is trying to access localstorage, then Javascript use `window.localstorage`, but it can't access because the only way to do that is just running the code in client side.

this is my store:

```
// persistedState.js
import Vuex from "vuex"
import createPersistedState from "vuex-persistedstate"

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    token: null,
  },
  getters: {
    isAuthenticated(state) {
      return state.token !== null
    },
  },
  mutations: {
    setToken(state, token) {
      state.token = token
    },
  },
  plugins: [createPersistedState()],
})

export default store
```

and my plguins

```
// nuxt.config.js
  plugins: [
    "@/plugins/chart.js",
    { src: "@/plugins/persistedState.js", ssr: false },
  ],
```

look that even I setting ssr equals false, it doesnt work

detail: I'm trying using it in my middleware

Comment: It should not be `ssr: false` but rather `mode: 'client'`. As for the rest, check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67751550/8816585

Comment: I already tried and nothing :(