How to pre render all the routes in Nuxt 3 application .output automatically (without hard coding and specifying them specifically)?
When I generate a .output folder for deployment in Nuxt 3 using nuxt generate or npm run generate, routes aren't pre-rendered automatically. I added prerender to nuxt.config.ts hooks to generate specific routes, but it only works for hardcoded routes. How can I pre-render all routes automatically without hardcoding them?
Following is my nuxt.config.ts file contents:
export default {
  modules: ["@nuxtjs/tailwindcss", "unplugin-fonts/nuxt", "@nuxtjs/i18n"],

  ssr: false,

  hooks: {
    'prerender:routes' ({ routes }) {
      routes.add('/page1')
    },
  }
}

In this case, only the page1.vue route is generated within .output. Hence, I need to add all routes within my Nuxt 3 config file one by one, but I want to pretend all of them automatically when I run npm run generate or nuxt generate. How to pre-render all the routes automatically? I am using the following version of Nuxt or Vue in my application:
"vue": "^3.3.4",
"nuxt": "^3.5.2",

I looked into the Nuxt 3 documentation (https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/prerendering#prerenderroutes) and found an experimental way of doing and that works for me temporarily nuxt.config.ts:
export default {
  modules: ["@nuxtjs/tailwindcss", "unplugin-fonts/nuxt", "@nuxtjs/i18n"],

  ssr: false,

  experimental: {
    inlineRouteRules: true,
  },
}


and within each of my routes/pages I need to add the following:
<script setup>
  defineRouteRules({ prerender: true });
</script>

Adding this manually to each page is tedious for large applications, especially with extended Nuxt modules. I need an automatic approach to pre-render all routes. Is there a way to pre-render all the routes automatically? I believe it was working before with the same set-up and suddenly it seems to have stopped working.

This was the way for Nuxt2, there is probably a similar way for Nuxt3: https://v2.nuxt.com/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-generate#function-which-returns-a-promise Maybe check on Nitro's side.

@kissu Thanks for the response. I am running in my local environment to deploy in production. I saw few examples of the same but which API should I request like in your example its 'https://my-api/users' but what should be in my application when running for clients side code? Also there is no direct approach rather than adding additional method to find the routes?

Your routes are probably generated based on some endpoint, use that one to craft them. The client-side calls can stay like that, nothing more is needed there. There is maybe a direct approach, I haven't used this one recently, please check on the Github.

set ssr: true

@typed-sigterm I tried that approach as well but I get the error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'userAgent')  not sure from where it stems it just mentions the error but when I do build npm run build or run the application everything works fine there. So unable to figure out the issue.

You do not have any user agents on the server.

@kissu Sorry but I am unable to follow you. So what shall I do about the userAgent issue? Since I am pretty new to these rendering things don't have a lot of knowledge on this.

@BATMAN_2008 code running on the client-side and server-side are 2 different things, you do not have Window for example, media-queries or anything. You need to learn quite a lot of things overall, I recommend you go incremental regarding the features you want to implement. You can otherwise use some tricks to skip the code to run on the server-side. Writing proper isomorphic code (that runs on both client and server-side) is a bit difficult and takes some practice.

@kissu The code is currently running on the client-side in my local system. I use different libraries such as CodeMirror etc and I believe if I use ssr:true then due to this library I get the error. I do don't use window/media directly within my code but seems like these libraries use and due to that I get the error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'userAgent')

Yeah, as told above this API is not available on the server. Check this answer for some solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67751550/8816585

The default behavior for Nuxt prerendering is to run a crawler starting from your site index and then following and rendering all the links that it discovers as well as to prerender the pages in your /pages directory. The only time you need to manually specify the routes is if the routes are dynamic and the specific dynamic route pages are unreachable through the regular crawling of your site links.
From the docs about prerendering

Load the HTML of your application's root route (/), any non-dynamic pages in your ~/pages directory, and any other routes in the nitro.prerender.routes array.
Save the HTML and payload.json to the ~/.output/public/ directory to be served statically.
Find all anchor tags () in the HTML to navigate to other routes.
Repeat steps 1-3 for each anchor tag found until there are no more anchor tags to crawl.

If, for some reason, you have a page you wish to prerender which is both a dynamic route and not linked to anywhere on your site you can manually specify the page to be prerendered in your defineNuxtConfig. Be aware, though, that if you have to do this for content on your site it means that there isn't any way for users to get to that content from the regular browsing of your site, and this can indicate a discoverability problem. It may be a better idea to fix the lack of discoverability of your content rather than forcing the prerendering directly.
