# "window is not defined" when import @microsoft/teams-js in nuxt js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, microsoft-teams

this happens when i try to import @microsoft/teams-js

```html
<template>
  <Tutorial />
</template>    

<script>
import * as microsoftTeams from '@microsoft/teams-js'   
export default {
  name: 'IndexPage'
}
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: This is answered [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54979644/window-is-not-defined-in-nuxt-js)

Comment: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/concepts/server-side-rendering#server-vs-browser-environments